# enter plain text in scrollview or texview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I want to enter text that I receive from json parsing and formatting a textview scrollview or as advised me to, so I want to make
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, self.scrollView.frame.size.width - 20, 200)];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.text = @"Lorem ipsum text";
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]; // or use [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18];
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

So on and so forth, for every text you have, you add a label and change its properties, add new ones or subtract existing ones as you please.

Comment: the problem is that in a textview for example can only make [textview setText: text] and in a scrollview addSubview only one, and if I have several items that add as I do?

Comment: you make `UILabel * label2 = [[UILabel alloc] ....` and the same for `UITextView` ...